# Character entered by user is breaking xml decoding done by xml_parse_into_struct

Tags: php, mysql

thanks for answering!
This is about PHP/MySQL

The user enters some text that is then processed through  `htmlentities()`:

```
$new_userinput = htmlentities($userinput, ENT_QUOTES);
```

This entry is stored in an XML:

```
...
<entrylist>
    <list>$new_userinput</list>
    <info>$someinfo</info>
</entrylist>
...
```

The xml file is stored in a database in UTF-8 format. The HTML for the site is also set with UTF-8.

What we observed is with a specific input, the xml being processed by:

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmlentry, $values, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);`
```

is not processed properly by the `xml_parse_into_struct()`.

What we see in the database is the following:

```
...
<note>Creatives share shots&acirc;€”small screenshots.</note>
...
```

Comment: You should indent your code so it renders properly (read the faq). anyway - Have you checked the string you're saving to the database before you saved it? The problem might be with htmlentities and not the data storage.

Comment: htmlentities is working in our database where it doesn't store xml, but when it gets to the entries that store xml, htmlentities stops working. could it be that we need a DTD?

Comment: What you are showing in your question is perfectly valid XML.  What problem are you seeing?  Is the acirc + euro + right double quote the bytes of a UTF-8 encoding of something else?

Comment: just tried that phil it didn't work

Comment: @Samuel What does the original `$userinput` string look like?

Comment: we tried many different special char, and all of them didn't work. even copyright char `&copy;` didn't work!

Comment: The lion's share of the entities produced by `htmlentities` (including `&acirc;`) aren't valid in bog-standard XML. What exactly do you mean by "not processed properly?" Are there warnings?

Comment: this is the code the outputs the error message
`if ($max_note != $max_url) {
error_log(sprintf("%s: %d: db xml error %d vs %d", __FILE__, __LINE__, $max_note, $max_url), 3,"/public_html/somewebsite/errorlog23.txt");  
die ("database xml error</br>"); 
}`

Comment: _htmlentities (including &acirc;) aren't valid in bog-standard XML_ does that mean we need some kind of DTD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the charset in `htmlentities()`, eg

```
$new_userinput = htmlentities($userinput, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

To illustrate

```
echo htmlentities("€", ENT_QUOTES); // &acirc;?&not;

echo htmlentities("€", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); // &euro;
```

Comment: i just noticed that adding utf-8 did work, but on another problem. we're still get the same problem